# Getting "TypeError: cis.createLoader is not a function" unit testing BsDatepickerDirective

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-bootstrap

The following is a piece of code of my unit testing.

```
let BsDatepickerConfigStub = {};

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        ...
        providers: [
            { provide: BsDatepickerConfig, useValue: BsDatepickerConfigStub }
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GoalDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Whenever I run the test

```
it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I get this error:

TypeError: cis.createLoader is not a function at new BsDatepickerDirective

What is right way to mock all Bootstrap items in unit testing?